# Insert a document JSON from URL in mongodb with java

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I'm new in MongoDb and I have to upload a file in MongoDB with a java program.
I tried to write something but I do not know if it's the right way.
Can someone help me?
My difficulty is that the json file I have to upload is in a link address.
can mongodb read and upload the document to a database through java language?
I load the code below.
Thank you.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.bson.Document;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.FindIterable;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import com.mongodb.util.JSON;


public class mongodb {

public static void main (String args []) throws IOException {

    MongoClient mongo = null;
    MongoDatabase db = null;

    try {
        /**** Connect to MongoDB ****/
        mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);

        /**** Get database ****/
        db = mongo.getDatabase("db_plant");

        System.out.println("Successfully connected to database");           
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
    }

    DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("plants");

    final String URL = "https://www.plants.usda.gov/java/downloadData?fileName=plantlst.txt&static=true";
    String json = getTextFromUrl(URL);

    DBObject dbObject = (DBObject)JSON.parse(json);
    collection.insert(dbObject);

    DBCursor cursorDocJSON = collection.find();
    while (cursorDocJSON).hasNext() {
        System.out.println(cursorDocJSON).next();
    }
    collection.remove(new BasicDBObject();
}

private static String getTextFromUrl(String uRL) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: what error you are getting , mention that too.

Comment: At line 41: DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("plants");
Multiple markers at this line:
 - Debug Current Instruction Pointer
 - Type mismatch: cannot convert from MongoCollection<Document> to DBCollection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the old API.
If you use the [Mongo java driver](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/) 3.X, the correct api is :

```
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("plants");

Document dbObject = Document.parse(json);

MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find().iterator();
```